# Expression (in equation) for an inverse function.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

It was given that $g:[0,1]\rightarrow[0,2]$ defined by $g(x) = x + f(x)$, where $f:[0,1]\rightarrow[0,1]$ is Cantor function with $$f(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_n}{3^n}) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{b_n}{2^n}.$$
I know $g$ is invertible ( I have proven it is bijective. ) Thus the inverse of $g$, that is $g^{-1}$ exists. My problem is, how to express $g^{-1}$? From $g(x) = x+f(x)$, I have $x = g^{-1}(x + f(x))$ but then I don't know how to continue on anymore.

Any clue ?

Comment: Why do you need an expression for it? Are you trying to calculate specific values?

Comment: How is $b_n$ defined in terms of $a_n$?

Comment: @martycohen, is it $b_n = \frac{a_n}{2}$ if $a_n\in \{0,2\}$ and $b_n = 1$ with $b_{N} = 0$ for $N\geq{n+1}$ if $a_n = 1 $?